# Flutter color of an asset

Tags: android, flutter, svg, colors

Is there any way to set the color of an SVG asset as a static variable?
for example instead of having it like stroke="#0059ee8" stroke="@color/primary"

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `enums.dart` file under `lib/constants` where you can maintain all the colors like:

```
const C_THEME_COLOR = 0xFFF46523;
```

And you can access the color where ever you need like:

```
backgroundColor: Color(C_THEME_COLOR),
```

Add import like:

```
import 'package:my_project/constants/enums.dart';
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I use it inside an xml file like the svg's?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding color to the SvgPicture widget itself. Example using flutter_svg: ^0.22.0 package. Below is a snippet of the same.

```
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
      Container(
        height: 30,
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
        'assets/svg/add_money.svg',
         color:
        Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
     )
```

Comment: Yeah, that way works but it is not exactly what I want. Think for example that I have an svg with 2 or more colors, this code will change every color. What exactly I want is to replace the hex color from the svg's code with a static variable, like the colors we use for native android applications (resources/values/colors.xml -> @color/primary_color)